# Can't upload files to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Can't upload files to the server. I've used `npm install express-fileupload` and also did the `var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')` and `app.use(fileUpload())`. And while calling

```js
router.post('/add-products',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files.image);
```

It says cannot read image of null.

Comment: show your upload codes, and show your nodejs codes https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you a working full example.

Project structure:

```
- storage (empty folder)
- routes
 -> upload.route.js
- controllers
 -> upload.controller.js
index.js
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const route = require('./routes/upload.route');
app.use('/', route);

let port = 8000;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`API listens localhost:${port}`);
```

This is your `upload.route.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { uploadController } = require('../controllers/upload.controller');

router.use('/media/upload', uploadController);

module.exports = router;
```

This is `upload.controller.js`

```
const formidable = require('formidable');
const path = require('path');

exports.upload = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        // Receive the media and store it
        let [uploadPath, filename] = await processUpload(req);

        return res
            .status(200)
            .send({
                success: 1,
                message: "File uploaded",
                filename,
                uploadPath
            });

    } catch (error) {

        return res
            .status(400)
            .send({
                success: 0,
                message: "Ops! Something went wrong",
                errorObject: error.message
            });
    }
}

function processUpload(req) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let uploadDir = __dirname + `/../storage`;

            // We used helper formidable package
            let form = new formidable.IncomingForm()

            form.multiples = true;
            form.keepExtensions = true;

            // Upload path
            form.uploadDir = uploadDir;

            let result;

            form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {

                if (!file.type) reject(new Error("No media specified!"));

                const fileExt = path.extname(file.name);

                let filename = "test" + fileExt;

                file.path = path.join(uploadDir, filename);

                // Return the path where file uploaded
                result = [file.path, uuid];
            });

            form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
                if (err) return reject("Upload failed.");
                resolve(result);
            });


        } catch (error) {
            reject("Upload failed.");
        }
    });
}
```

When you call `localhost:8000/media/upload` with a `POST` or `PUT` request with postman `form-data`. You can see the uploaded file under the `storage` folder in the project.

Let me know if something goes wrong with the code

Note: You need to use [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) (For uploading) package to run the example

Comment: Your welcome. Can you please accept this as answer?